# Movement of tiles between "mosaic of tiles" and "one tile zoomed and others as thumbnails"

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, responsive-design, thumbnails

I have an interface with a few panels, like here with a mosaic of 6 panels, using multiple `display: flex` div, with `flex-direction` column or row.

I'd like that, **when clicking/touching on *one* panel, this one becomes nearly full size, and the other panels are in a left column as "thumbnails".**

I don't see how I can make this with my current design with multiple `flex` elements inside each other.

Question: how do you create such a "click on one tile to zoom it and move other tiles as a column of thumbnails" feature?

[image]

```css
.horizontal { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; gap: 1em; }
.vertical { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around; flex-direction: column; gap: 1em; }
.box { width: 150px; height: 100px; background-color: #eee; }
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
    <div class="vertical">
        <div class="box">A</div>
        <div class="box">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="vertical">
        <div class="box">C</div>
        <div class="box">D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="vertical">
        <div class="box">E</div>
        <div class="box">F</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid` and use the `grid-template-areas` property to put a space where you need the larger image. I've put the skeleton of one up for you but you'll need to neaten up the box sizes a bit.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.container > div').forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove('clicked'); 
    });
    document.querySelector('.container').classList.remove('clicked');
    
    const clickedElement = event.target;
    if(clickedElement.tagName=="IMG") {
      clickedElement.closest('.container').classList.add('clicked');    
      event.target.closest('.box').classList.add('clicked');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.container.clicked {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, fit-content(0));
  grid-template-areas: ". img" ". img" ". img" ". img" ". img" ". img";
}

.box.clicked {
  grid-area: img;
  width: 450px;
}

.box.clicked img {
  width: 100%;
  animation: scalein 0.5s;
}

.box img {
  animation: scaleout 0.3s;
}

.container.clicked .box:not(.clicked) {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 80px;
}

@keyframes scalein {
  0% {
    transform: scale(50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(102%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(100%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(150%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200'></div>
  <div class="box"><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/242/200'></div>
  <div class="box"><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/241/200'></div>
  <div class="box"><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/240/200'></div>
  <div class="box"><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/238/200'></div>
  <div class="box"><img src='https://picsum.photos/id/239/200'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Icing on the cake, do you think there can be animation when the tiles are moving?

Comment: I've added a few keyframes. I'm a better coder than a UX designer so you might be able to do better than me.

Comment: In the "clicked" view, I would like the main clicked box to take 2/3 of the full width, and the left thumbnails to take 1/3 of the full width. I tried to replace 450px by 66% and 80px by 33% but then nothing is displayed. How would you do that @Adam?